# What to do with getParameter() in the java code?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, applet, jcreator

I am making a java applet which has to play video file. I have searched a code on the net but it gives an error at `getParameter`

Here is the code...

```
 public void init() {

        //$ System.out.println("Applet.init() is called");
        setLayout(null);
        setBackground(Color.white);
        panel = new Panel();
        panel.setLayout( null );
        add(panel);
        panel.setBounds(0, 0, 320, 240);

        // input file name from html param
        String mediaFile = null;
        // URL for our media file
        MediaLocator mrl = null;
        URL url = null;

        // Get the media filename info.
        // The applet tag should contain the path to the
        // source media file, relative to the html page.

       // Error here: Invalid media file parameter

        if ((mediaFile = getParameter("C:\\Users\\asim\\Documents\\JCreator LE\\MyProjects\\SimplePlayerApplet\\src\\Movie.avi")) == null)
            Fatal("Invalid media file parameter");

        try {
            url = new URL(getDocumentBase(), mediaFile);
            mediaFile = url.toExternalForm();
        } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
        }
```

Here is the link to whole code :

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/SimplePlayerApplet.java.html

Comment: Based on the 'answers' provided already, can you update your code and HTML and then paste them both above, including any errors you may still be getting.

Answer (score 1):

How are you 'invoking' your applet?

It seems you are trying to specify the 'parameter' as something that sits on the local file system yet you are building an 'applet' so you should really be invoking it via HTML and then pass the 'parameter in as such:

```
<applet code=SimplePlayerApplet.class width=320 height=300>
<param name="file" value="sun.avi">
</applet>
```

and thus your `getParameter` call should still be for `"file"`. Just as in the code you were using before.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thoughts here:

1. You're using a file that reside in the local filesystem. Applets by default don't have an access to the filesystem. There is a comment above the method from the tutorial. And its clearly states the the file should be relative to html page and reside on server. Just read carefully comments there.
2. The example uses Applet (the class they provide extends the Applet) - its an old approach and now its deprecated. Basically what it does is uses AWT instead of newer Swing. So you should look for an example of using JApplet instead.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should place the parameter in HTMLpart, this would make the applet independend from the content. You confused the parameter name with its value.

```
<HTML> <BODY>
<APPLET CODE="SimplePlayerApplet.class" WIDTH=320 HEIGHT=240>
 <PARAM NAME="filename" VALUE="C:\\Users\\asim\\Documents\\JCreator LE\\MyProjects\\SimplePlayerApplet\\src\\Movie.avi">

</APPLET>
</BODY> </HTML>


 if ((mediaFile = getParameter("filename")) == null)
    ...
```

In order to access the filesystem you need to sign the applet.

The Line:

```
 URL(getDocumentBase(), mediaFile);
```

tries to open the mediaFile relative from DocumentBase. This means relative to the URL of the document in which this applet is embedded.
See alse [Applet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html).

Thus the easiest way to get it run would be to copy your Movie.avi in the same folder where your HTML-File resides and use

```
URL(getDocumentBase(), "Movie.avi");
```

After that you should make it configurable by supplying the filename as a parameter.